Why edge id in net.xml and edge id from report getting by running SUMO with --edgedata-ouput is different?
I'm working with OSM dataset in SUMO.
For .net.xml file, I'm using extracted xml file from OSM graph dataset.
Following part of code is about edge information.
    <edge id="1196" from="275538795" to="49331073" priority="14" type="highway.motorway" spreadType="center">
        <lane id="1196_0" index="0" allow="private emergency authority army vip passenger hov taxi bus coach delivery truck trailer motorcycle evehicle custom1 custom2" speed="39.44" length="248.47" shape="599326.72,19427.92 599089.73,19353.27"/>
        <lane id="1196_1" index="1" allow="private emergency authority army vip passenger hov taxi bus coach delivery truck trailer motorcycle evehicle custom1 custom2" speed="39.44" length="248.47" shape="599327.68,19424.87 599090.69,19350.22"/>
        <lane id="1196_2" index="2" allow="private emergency authority army vip passenger hov taxi bus coach delivery truck trailer motorcycle evehicle custom1 custom2" speed="39.44" length="248.47" shape="599328.64,19421.82 599091.65,19347.16"/>
        <lane id="1196_3" index="3" allow="private emergency authority army vip passenger hov taxi bus coach delivery truck trailer motorcycle evehicle custom1 custom2" speed="39.44" length="248.47" shape="599329.60,19418.76 599092.62,19344.11"/>
    </edge>

And following part of code is report I got from running simulation in SUMO with --edgeData-output option.
 <edge id="-19724" sampledSeconds="7.81" traveltime="7.60" overlapTraveltime="7.81" density="0.06" laneDensity="0.03" occupancy="0.01" waitingTime="0.00" timeLoss="3.25" speed="16.63" speedRelative="0.60" departed="0" arrived="0" entered="1" left="1" laneChangedFrom="0" laneChangedTo="0"/>

My plan was using the simulation result in python code with OSM environment. But when I search edge information with edge id in report, it doesn't work.
What edge id refers to?
And do you know how can I convert edge ID to OSM wayID?
Thank you in advance.
